# Slow performance with Ubuntu 18.04 after more then a year using and developing with it

Tags: boot, 18.04, performance

I'm using this computer for one year and a half with Ubuntu 18.04, and It is taking more or less 3 minutes to turn on the OS, after start the SO, for open the software take long time to open, at least 2 minutes.

The hardwares are:

- Intel® Core™ i7-7500U CPU @ 2.70GHz × 4
- Memory RAM 7.7 GiB
- 1 TB HD
- Graphics Intel® HD Graphics 620 (Kaby Lake GT2)

I'm running Steam, Firefox (6 tabs), Terminal, and right open "Show application" for screen show the `top` command on bash for try understand more  the waste of performance. This image are following:

[image]

I checked that almost all my service are disable on start up. I also change the swapiness to 1 (activate swap only when 99% of the MEM are in use).

I was planning to format and became in heaven again, but I'm here as only hope for someone that knows more, to then me tell me something that happens or I'm doing wrong.

More information about services:

```
service --status-all
```

- [ + ]  acpid
- [ - ]  alsa-utils
- [ - ]  anacron
- [ + ]  apache-htcacheclean
- [ - ]  apache2
- [ + ]  apparmor
- [ + ]  apport
- [ + ]  avahi-daemon
- [ + ]  bluetooth
- [ - ]  cgroupfs-mount
- [ - ]  console-setup.sh
- [ + ]  cron
- [ - ]  cryptdisks
- [ - ]  cryptdisks-early
- [ + ]  cups
- [ + ]  cups-browsed
- [ + ]  dbus
- [ - ]  dns-clean
- [ - ]  docker
- [ + ]  gdm3
- [ + ]  grub-common
- [ - ]  hwclock.sh
- [ + ]  inetutils-inetd
- [ + ]  irqbalance
- [ + ]  kerneloops
- [ - ]  keyboard-setup.sh
- [ + ]  kmod
- [ - ]  lvm2
- [ + ]  lvm2-lvmetad
- [ + ]  lvm2-lvmpolld
- [ - ]  mdadm
- [ - ]  mdadm-waitidle
- [ - ]  mysql
- [ + ]  network-manager
- [ + ]  networking
- [ - ]  nfs-common
- [ + ]  nfs-kernel-server
- [ + ]  openvpn
- [ + ]  php7.0-fpm
- [ + ]  php7.1-fpm
- [ - ]  plymouth
- [ - ]  plymouth-log
- [ + ]  postfix
- [ - ]  pppd-dns
- [ - ]  procps
- [ - ]  proftpd
- [ + ]  rpcbind
- [ - ]  rsync
- [ + ]  rsyslog
- [ - ]  saned
- [ - ]  screen-cleanup
- [ + ]  speech-dispatcher
- [ - ]  spice-vdagent
- [ - ]  ssh
- [ + ]  tlp
- [ + ]  ubuntu-fan
- [ + ]  udev
- [ + ]  ufw
- [ + ]  unattended-upgrades
- [ - ]  uuidd
- [ + ]  virtualbox
- [ + ]  whoopsie
- [ - ]  x11-common

Just to say, it used to start up in 15 seconds when are totally clean the OS.
Do you know something that could be happening or can helps in this environment?

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04 was released in late 2018-April (thus 18.04) so hasn't been out 18 months yet.  Your understanding of swappiness is flawed (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SwapFaq#What_is_swappiness_and_how_do_I_change_it.3F), but have you looked at what you autostart?

Answer (score 1):

There is a possibility that you're looking at the software and it could be hardware based.

Many slowdowns are actually caused by the hard disk, especially HD (spinning disks).  If you've got a fairly full drive it'll be spending more time searching for the correct blocks to read. When you wipe the drive it's back to being fresh with barely anything on it. The more programs and files you create the slower it will get as it has way more to search through (I've really simplified how disks & file systems work).

The best way around this I would suggest is putting a SSD to install the OS on to in the machine and using the large HDD for file storage (/home).

Comment: I get it, but the solution it isn't upgrade the hardware, it's better management of the existent one somehow, or at least format the OS

Comment: And my Driver is only about 30% used.